# "From date - To date" to specify a period of time

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase-request, time

How I can translate *from date* and *to date* to specify a period of time? In my web application there are a few places where a user can input the period of time when something happened in an employee's life. For example:

> From date: 2013-01-01
>   To date: 2014-12-31
>   Address: Fulton Streed, NY
>
> From date: 2015-01-01
>   To date: Now
>   Address: First Streed, LA

Comment: You may want to add some information describing why this is not a simple translation request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Von: (From date)
>
> Bis: (To date)

is usually understood very well when combined with date pickers.

Screenshot from the production version of a fat client including account bookings filterable by date interval:

[image: von bis date picker]